# Curl parallel downloads with different "Range" headers

Tags: linux, bash, curl, concurrency, parallel-processing

Now that curl has parallel download support. Is it possible to add different byte range headers per concurrent download in the config file?

```
For example if I put this in my config.txt config file:

 
    url = "http://www.example.com"
    header = "Range: bytes=0-1024"
    output = "chunk1"
    url = "http://www.example.com"
    header = "Range: bytes=1025-2049"
    output = "chunk2"
    url = "http://www.example.com"
    header = "Range: bytes=2050-3074"
    output = "chunk3"

and run

curl --parallel --parallel-max 60 --config config.txt

I get 3 chunks downloaded concurrently but always the first byte range 0-1024 instead of each specific byte range per file. Is it impossible or is my config file incorrect?

After running curl with verbose:

> curl -vv --parallel --parallel-max 60 --config config.txt

It shows that curl regroups all ranges and add them to each request therefore only the first one is kept.
 
> Range: bytes=0-1024
> Range: bytes=1025-2049
> Range: bytes=2050-3074


Thank you for your help.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on curl's github page (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5774), credit goes to Dan Fandrich @dfandrich:

> You probably need the "next" option between requests to make them use separate headers.

Putting just **next** didn't work in my case but with **--next** in the config file it worked!!!

Modified config file is now:

> ```
> url = "http://www.example.com"
> header = "Range: bytes=0-1024"
> output = "chunk1"
> --next
> url = "http://www.example.com"
> header = "Range: bytes=1025-2049"
> output = "chunk2"
> --next
> url = "http://www.example.com"
> header = "Range: bytes=2050-3074"
> output = "chunk3"
> ```

Thank you

Comment: which version of 'curl' did you use?
I doesn't work for me on linux with 7.81.0.
When i use "next" or "--next" is only creates the 1st request.

Comment: I used version curl 7.85.0

Comment: @TryingHard but --next doesn't work with parallel, right? So you are getting those urls sequentially....

Comment: "If you’re doing parallel transfers (with -Z), curl will do URLs in parallel only until the --next separator." - https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/03/02/curl-ootw-next/

Comment: @Andrew, no I'm getting them in parallel. You need a new version of Curl to get parallel downloads.